# Getting Daily Limit for unauthenticated use Exceeded

Tags: xamarin

Getting Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup

when executing the following code given in the Xamarin demo

```
async void OnAuthenticationCompleted (object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsAuthenticated) {
                // If the user is authenticated, request their basic user data from Google
                // UserInfoUrl = https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
                var request = new OAuth2Request ("GET", new Uri (Constants.UserInfoUrl), null, e.Account);
                var response = await request.GetResponseAsync ();
                if (response != null) {
                    // Deserialize the data and store it in the account store
                    // The users email address will be used to identify data in SimpleDB
                    string userJson = response.GetResponseText ();
                    App.User = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User> (userJson);
                    e.Account.Username = App.User.Email;
                    AccountStore.Create ().Save (e.Account, App.AppName);
                }
            }
            // If the user is logged in navigate to the TodoList page.
            // Otherwise allow another login attempt.
            App.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke ();
        }
```

This is the error I am getting

```
"error":{
"errors": [
{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
"message" :"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
"extendedHelp" : "https://code.google/apis/console"
}
],
"code":403,
"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
}
```

Comment: Which specific Xamarin demo?  They have lots of sample projects.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. Is there some reason to think that you haven't exceeded the unauthenticated use limit.?

Comment: @jason: TodoAWSAuth at the following link https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoAWSAuth/

Comment: @JamesK : I have tried it less than 10 times and don't think that was the reason.

Comment: Did you follow the steps to create your own client ids, secrets, etc?

Comment: @jason: I did exactly as given in the demo, downloaded the source code and when running it, I am getting the above error

Comment: there are extensive instructions included on the page that you need to follow - just running the source code as is will not work

Comment: @jason: I did all the steps stated and added all the ids required. I added the  following as redirecturl "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me" in the code and in google developer console.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the redireturl to "http://example.com/oauth2callback" and in the ios project modified the ATS setting by adding the following key in info.plist

NSAppTransportSecurity -- Dictionary
  NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent -- Boolean -- Yes